# qcow2 and qemu-system-arm

Tags: qemu

I just tried booting up a Debian ARMel build using QEMU on my Ubuntu machine as follows :-

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -kernel vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-versatile -initrd initrd.img-3.2.0-4-versatile -hda debian_wheezy_armel_desktop.qcow2 -append "root=/dev/sda1"
```

But I get this error message:

```
qemu-system-arm: -hda debian_wheezy_armel_desktop.qcow2: 'scsi0-hd0' uses a qcow2 feature which is not supported by this qemu version: QCOW version 3
```

I have not come across any way to convert qcow2 to qcow3; does anyone know what the latest qemu version that supports qcow2 is? I'd like to try installing that.

Comment: What's the error that makes you think it doesn't understand qcow2?  Also, qemu-img may be able to convert to qcow3, though I haven't tried myself

Comment: @EricRenouf Thanks. I've pasted the error message. I tried using qemu-img, but it too complains about now being able to work with qemu2.

Answer (score 1):

Given that error message it seems, according to [this site](http://blog.wikichoon.com/2014/12/virt-manager-10-creates-qcow2-images.html) that the problem may have been with how virt-manager created the image, and you might be able to use `qemu-img` after all like so:

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O qcow2 -o compat=0.10 $ORIGPATH $NEWPATH
```

to convert from a "broken" qcow2 to a usable qcow2 file.